# How to delete folder from previously deleted Web App under IIS 8.5 Default Web Site?

Tags: asp.net, directory, virtual, delete-file, iis-8.5

Help - I can't delete a folder that used to be a virtual folder in IIS 8.5.

I'm developing the install portion of a web app on IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012R2), and have run into a situation where I'm unable to get rid of a folder that was installed for the app.  I have deleted the app, the app pool, and the virtual directory, tried to recreate virtual directory, tried to convert to app and back.  Nothing I've tried has worked.

Trying to delete the folder in File Explorer, I get "You require permission from Administrators to make changes to this folder".  My user is member of local administrators on the server (my user is in a trusted domain, the server is in our test domain).  If I try to clear the Read-only flag, I get Access Denied, but with the option to Continue as Administrator, but still can't proceed.

I've tried stopping the Server in IIS Manager, stopping the services (W3SVC, AppHostSvc, and WAS), but to no avail.

I need to be able to test my install by repeating it (both the first-time install steps, and the Web Deployment Package install).

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting the server, I was able to delete the folder using File Explorer.  Apparently, it was in some invalid "state".